# Identifying Irreducible Polynomials in a ring R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm wondering under what conditions we can say that a polynomial is irreducible in a ring $R[x]$? For example, consider the polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f(x)=x^2-2x-1$. Then, in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ we can factor $f$ as follows:
$$f(x)=(x-1-\sqrt{2})(x-1+\sqrt{2})$$
What I would like to say is that since $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$, it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and is therefore irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Is this a valid argument to make? Following that logic, couldn't I just claim that since $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}$ it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

This seems intuitive and obvious to me, however, if it were true, it seems like there would be a theorem stating this in my book, which there isn't. So, my question is, is it possible to reduce a polynomial even if has no roots in $R[x]$?

Comment: This is true but you need to justify the leap from irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ to irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, using e.g. Gauss's lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)

Comment: Yes, I was using Gauss's lemma to move to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but my question is, why is necessarily true that if $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ it must therefore be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. And moreover, why can't we just say the same for integers? That is, if $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, it therefore is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: This is specific to the quadratic and cubic cases. The only way for a quadratic or cubic polynomial to factor is into two linear factors in the quadratic case and either three linear factors or one linear + one quadratic factor in the cubic case. So in all these cases there is at least one linear factor and hence at least one root. Taking the contrapositive, if there's no root then there's no nontrivial factorization. This argument continues to work over $\mathbb{Z}$ but only for monic polynomials, and it doesn't work starting in degree $4$ since a quartic can factor into two quadratics.